# How do I fetch/clone only a few branches using git-svn?

Tags: svn, git, branch, git-svn

The SVN repository that I am working with has a rather large number of branches.  I am only interested in working with three of them and maybe another new SVN branch that will be created in the future.  What I have figured out so far is that the command `git svn clone URL -T trunk -b branches -t tags` will clone all SVN branches and subsequent `git svn fetch` commands will also operate on all SVN branches.

Is there a way for me to specify the few branches that I want to work with? I most likely don't have enough disk space for all the SVN branches on my dev machine and  I'd like to avoid an extremely time-consuming `git svn clone` operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Multiple branches using git-svn](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/20070608113513/) shows how to selectively add Subversion branches to a `git-svn` repository.