# How to git svn fetch only branches/tags with certain patterns?

Tags: git, git-svn, git-branch

I want to check out Boost library using git-svn, and I only want to checkout trunk and tags starting from version 1.35, i.e. tags/release/Boost_1_35 and up.  My config looks like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    ignore-paths = ^tags/release/(?i:(?!boost)|[^/]*(?:beta|rc)|boost_(?:0|1_[1-2]|1_3[0-4]))[^/]*/
    url = https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
    tags = tags/release/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
```

However, git fetch still fetches tons of unrelated tags such as svn/tags/version_0-9-10 or svn/tags/version_0-9-10@44215.  I wonder what's the correct way of specifying ignore-paths to achieve this effect.

BTW: I've read [How do I fetch/clone only a few branches using git-svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892133/how-do-i-fetch-clone-only-a-few-branches-using-git-svn) but doesn't sounds a scalable solution.

Comment: [My answer on a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933748/how-do-git-svn-ignore-paths-work-ignoring-daily-build-tags/6937445#6937445) might be applicable for you too.

Comment: @MatrixFrog thanks.  I think it is pretty similar to what I mentioned, which is not quite scalable as boost is a pretty large repository.  Also I was worried when new branches appear, will git go through all the svn history again?  If yes, then it is not quite applicable to boost repository because it usually takes several days to checkout a complete boost repository using git.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. You probably want to leave it running overnight, possibly more than once if there's a ton of tags. Alternatively, it's possible that someone has already done the work and posted it somewhere, so you can just clone their git repo. In fact, google "boost git" -- it appears that has happened.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do so for certain branches, but since tags in svn are actually branches it should probably be the same:

After git svn init with "-t tags and -b branches" I have edited .git/config to be:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        ... url, fetch and stuff ... 
        branches = branches/rel-2.1/*:refs/remotes/svn/branches/rel-2.1/*
        branches = branches/rel-2.2/*:refs/remotes/svn/branches/rel-2.2/*
        branches = branches/rel-2.3/*:refs/remotes/svn/branches/rel-2.3/*
        branches = branches/rel-2.4/*:refs/remotes/svn/branches/rel-2.4/*
        branches = branches/rel-2.5/*:refs/remotes/svn/branches/rel-2.5/*
```

I used a simple python code to generate the relevant lines and copied it to .git/config:

```
for x in range(1,6):
   print branches = "     branches/rel-2.{0}/*:refs/remotes/svn/branches/rel-2.{0}/*".format(x)
```

Not as scalable as regex, but that's the best I could find.

Comment: as per above it will fetch all branches what is way to exclude ,, because ihave over 20 branches to inculde and 3 to exclude